# SetLockoutEndDateAsync not updating value in db

Tags: c#, owin

I have an ajax form that posts back when a user clicks a checkbox to lock a user out.  When I check the LockoutEndDateUtc column for said user remains NULL.

Here is my Json Method.

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AjaxUpdateUserLockout(string userId)
    {
        string message = "";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId)) message = "Unable to find user!";

        try
        {
            var result = UpdateLockoutDate(userId);
            message = "Success";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            NLogger.Error(ex);
            message = "Error updating user!";
        }

        return new JsonResult()
        {
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            Data = new { result = message }
        };
    }
```

And here is the method I have which sets the lockout date

```
    private async Task<IdentityResult> UpdateLockoutDate(string userId)
    {
        var user = ApplicationUserManager.FindById(userId, new AFFirst2Entities());


        if (user.LockoutEndDateUtc != null && user.LockoutEndDateUtc != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            return await ApplicationUserManager.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(userId, DateTimeOffset.MinValue);
        }
        else
        {
            return await ApplicationUserManager.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(userId, DateTimeOffset.MaxValue);
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something? The LockoutEnabled column is set to true for all users.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by setting `user.LockoutEndDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow`, instead of using the `SetLockoutEndDateAsync` method.